# Official APIs for postal stamps releases by French postal service La Poste

Tags: data-request, transportation, france

*Inspired by [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/25106/were-postal-stamp-released-by-government-of-france-depicting-ltte-and-its-chief) about whether a given stamp has been released or not.*

Is there a publicly usable API (or RSS feed, or easily scrapable webpage) showing what postage stamps have been released by French postal service [La Poste](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Poste_%28France%29)?

Preferably under a reuse-friendly license.

Details about the stamp would be appreciated:

- Name
- Price
- Release date
- Image
- Dimensions, shape
- Description

It is not so much about existing and past stamps, and more about being very up-to-date regarding new (and possibly future) releases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Universal Postal Union (UPU) keeps a database of issued stamps starting in 2002 (it does not go earlier). For France, you can find the stamps issued 2002-2014 here:

http://www.wnsstamps.post/en/

Copyright information from that website:

> © Copyright UPU - WADP
>   The stamp designs are the property of their respective issuing postal authority.
>   The issuing postal authorities have allowed the reproduction of the stamps displayed on this website.